# Передача JSON массива в Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Доброе утро. Просидел часа 2-3, в интернете куча примеров, но у меня не выходит.
Вот код с Ajax.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myStyles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

    <?php
    include "header.html";
    include "left_menu.php";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">

    <form id="form" action="" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="model"><br>
        <input id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
    <script language="JavaScript">
var input = document.getElementsByName("model");
input=input[0].value;
            // click on button submit
            $("#submit").on('click', function(){
                // send ajax
                $.ajax({

                    type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                    dataType : 'json', // data type
                    url: 'php/search_script.php', // url where to submit the request
                    data : {model:input}, // post data || get data
                    success : function() {
                        var name = <?php echo $json?>
                        console.log(name);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                        console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                    }
                })
            });

    </script>
</body>
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
</html>
```

Код PHP

```
<?php
$data=array();
header('Content-type: application/json');
$connect = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=weapon user=arakul password=1111") or die("dsfsdfg");
pg_set_client_encoding($connect,UTF-8);
$post = $_POST['model'];
$query = sprintf("SELECT description from model where title = 'M4'");
$result = pg_query($connect, $query) or die(pg_last_error($result));
while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = array($row["name"]);
}

$json=json_encode($data)

echo $json;
```

Это лишь один из вариантов. Пробовал вариантов 5-6 и ни один не выходит. На данный момент выдаёт ошибку:

```
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…} "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Nb (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4)
```

Помогите решить проблему. Пробовал уже не отправлять ничего через ajax, пробовал разные варианты JSON.parse и тд.То возвращается null, то вот такая ошибка.

Comment: Это `echo $post;` не закомментировано? Еще в браузере смотрите в инструментах разработчика тело ответа на ajax запрос.

Comment: Да. По идее, я хочу сделать поиск. Передать название модели, выполнить запрос и вернуть результат на страницу. Введённое значение отображается в php файле.

Comment: Вы не можете ни чего отправлять на вывод при ajax запросе, кроме строки json ответа.

Comment: Я читал, что можно из PHP вернуть массив в JSON и в JS его распарсить. После чего вывести.

Comment: Выражайтесь яснее. Что это `echo $post;`? И зачем оно нужно, если браузер ждет только `echo $json;` в ответ?

Comment: А, это я проверял или приходит значение из поля. Убрал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                success : function() {
                    var name = <?php echo $json?>
                    console.log(name);
                },
```

замените на

```
                success : function(name) {
                    console.log(name);
                },
```

Comment: В ответе пришёл [array(1)]. Парсить с помощью JSON.parse()?

Comment: @Андрей, отправляйте из php массив вменяемо, а не `$data[] = array($row["name"]);` Чем не устраивает отправка массива имен, а не массива массивов содержащих имена?

Comment: Я же говорю - это один из найденных вариантов. Я пробовал отправлять просто $data[] = $row

Comment: Если вам нужен массив имен, то делайте так `$data[] = $row["name"];`, если нужно одно имя, то так: `$data = $row["name"]; break;`. Какое содержимое вам нужно, так и делайте.

Comment: Ответьте ещё, пожалуйста. Как его привести в нормальный вид в JS, чтобы вывести, например, в блок? Как я писал выше? В консоли приходит нормальный результат, но в виде Object